# 3D camera position in XNA

Tags: xna

In XNA how can I get the camera position through calculate the model's boundingsphere or if there is other way to get the camera position except calculate the model's boundingsphere

Comment: A model's bounding sphere and the camera position are completely unrelated. Your question doesn't make sense. What have you got so far, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: while how can i get the camera position for the specifical model

Comment: Models don't specify a camera position.

Comment: in xna how can i set the appropriate position for camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the comments, if you are looking at positioning a camera, here is a great [tutorial](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_camera.html).